# Postgresql: sum of an ever-growing list

Tags: postgresql

I have a `select sum(field) from table where boolean_field = true` kind of query.

This are now about 8 million rows and only going to get bigger.

Understandably, Postgres does seq scan instead of index, to avoid having to load all of it into memory at once.

At least that's how I understand it.

What would be a good way to make this run at an acceptable speed, at any size?

EDIT: version is Postgres 11.2

EDIT2: Already using an index on `(boolean_field) where boolean_field = true`

Comment: There's no single solution. One option can be to pre-calculate partial sums. Perhaps on a per-day basis. Example: every day, sum the new records for that day, and write to a different table. Then do a `select sum(field) from day_table`, which will be much faster.

Comment: Which Postgres version? Current versions can spawn multiple threads for a single query which can speed up things like that if your server hardware can handle that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's verion 11.2 Still slow

Comment: How many rows to qualify for the where condition? Maybe a filtered index helps? `create index on the_table (field) where boolean_field`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As stated originally, about 8 million. Already using a partial index with the exact condition of the call.

Comment: You should have included that information about the index in the question (and "there are 8 million rows" could also mean the total size is 8 million, not the size of the result)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep a table that contains the sum:

```
START TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE table_sum (s double precision NOT NULL);

CREATE FUNCTION upd_sum() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
BEGIN
   CASE TG_OP
      WHEN 'INSERT' THEN
         IF NEW.boolean_field THEN
            UPDATE table_sum SET s = s + NEW.field;
         END IF;
         RETURN NEW;
      WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN
         IF NEW.boolean_field OR OLD.boolean_field THEN
            UPDATE table_sum
            SET s = s
                    + CASE WHEN NEW.boolean_field THEN NEW.field ELSE 0.0 END
                    - CASE WHEN OLD.boolean_field THEN OLD.field ELSE 0.0 END;
         END IF;
         RETURN NEW;
      WHEN 'DELETE' THEN
         IF OLD.boolean_field THEN
            UPDATE table_sum SET s = s - OLD.field;
         END IF;
         RETURN OLD;
      WHEN 'TRUNCATE' THEN
         UPDATE table_sum SET s = 0.0;
         RETURN NULL;
   END CASE;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER upd_sum1 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "table"
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd_sum();

CREATE TRIGGER upd_sum2 AFTER TRUNCATE ON "table"
   FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd_sum();

INSERT INTO table_sum
SELECT sum(field) FROM "table"
WHERE boolean_field;

COMMIT;
```

Some explanations:

- Documentation links to [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), [PL/pgSQL triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) and [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)
- This script is in a single transaction so that the counter is initialized correctly in the face of concurrent transactions. `CREATE TRIGGER` will take an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, so that all concurrent data access is blocked until the counter is initialized.